# column output-separator missing in ubuntu

Tags: linux, format

I have following file

```
-------------------:-----------------------------------------
hp-health agent: active
-------------------:-----------------------------------------
Vendor: HP
Product Name: ProLiant BL460c Gen9
Serial Number: Not Specified
CPUs: 48
CPU Model: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v3 @ 2.50GHz
Memory: 64G
-------------------:-----------------------------------------
br-mgmt: 10.65.3.71/21
br-storage: 10.60.3.71/21
br-vxlan: 10.63.3.71/21
-------------------:-----------------------------------------
Memory: 16384 MB - Ok
Memory: 16384 MB - Ok
Memory: 16384 MB - Ok
Memory: 16384 MB - Ok
-------------------:-----------------------------------------
```

I am running following command on centos7 to format using `column` command

```
# cat /tmp/foo.txt | column -s ':' -t -o '|'
-------------------|-----------------------------------------
hp-health agent    | active
-------------------|-----------------------------------------
Vendor             | HP
Product Name       | ProLiant BL460c Gen9
Serial Number      | Not Specified
CPUs               | 48
CPU Model          | Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v3 @ 2.50GHz
Memory             | 64G
-------------------|-----------------------------------------
br-mgmt            | 10.65.3.71/21
br-storage         | 10.60.3.71/21
br-vxlan           | 10.63.3.71/21
-------------------|-----------------------------------------
Memory             | 16384 MB - Ok
Memory             | 16384 MB - Ok
Memory             | 16384 MB - Ok
Memory             | 16384 MB - Ok
-------------------|-----------------------------------------
```

Now i am trying this on ubuntu 20.04 and noticed it has latest version of column command which doesn't have `-o, --output-separator separators` option. is there any other way i can format this on ubuntu?

```
Ubuntu# cat /tmp/foo.txt | column -s ':' -t -o '|'
column: invalid option -- 'o'
usage: column [-txne] [-c columns] [-s sep] [file ...]
```

Comment: Interesting ... did this work in previous versions of Ubuntu, and they made a "regression" from the `column` that usually comes with `util-linux` in favour of the one in `bsdmainutils`? I don't have any older versions of Ubuntu around, and never used that particular feature of `column`, so didn't notice.

Comment: You are correct here - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/1705437

Comment: Holy moly - so it's been like that for quite some time, and the redhat guys chose the more "modern" version.  That's almost as bad as using the old AIX grep instead of the GNU one ;)

Comment: So Debian have fixed it (taken the outdated column out in  `bsdmainutils` 12.1.1 early 2020) - beats me why Ubuntu still ships 11.1.2 ... according to that bug-report above they follow debian's packaging.